# How to configure two symfony applications in the same project

Tags: php, symfony-1.4

I'm using symfony for one of my projects. The application has already developed and using symfony 1.4.

Now I need to write a database upgrader for that application. The upgrader is using pure sql and this upgrader act as a separate project. I like to build the upgrader as a seperate symfony app which is located at the same root directory. The currunt folder structure is as follows.

```
application
|_ symfony
|  |_apps
|  |_cache
|  |_ .......more
|
|_upgrader
```

I need to link the upgrader folder as a sperate app with the current structure where I can use actions and templates as a normal symfony project.

I need to have it as a seperate app because the upgrader will run before the main application install.

Can someone explain me how to handle two app in a same symfony project and how to do it by keeping the upgrader app folder structure on the root directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use ./symfony generate:app in the command line. Have a look to ./symfony help generate:app